# I can not install request

Tags: node.js, express, request

I am trying to use the Marvel api and was going to use request to make the calls. I tried to run npm install request --save and I was given deprecated and error message's. I will include the dependencies, then the code and errors

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "ejs": "^2.7.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "marvel-api": "^1.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4"
  }

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");
var api = require('marvel-api');
/* var request = require("request"); */
var marvel = api.createClient({
    publicKey: 'taken out'
  , privateKey: 'taken out'
  });


app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}));


app.get("/", function(req,res){
    marvel.characters.findByName('spider-man')
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log('Found character ID', res.data[0].id);
    res.render("landing", {marvel:res.data[0].id});
    return marvel.characters.comics(res.data[0].id);
  })
  .then(function(res) {
    console.log('found %s comics of %s total', res.meta.count, res.meta.total);
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .fail(console.error)
  .done();


})

npm install request --save
npm WARN deprecated hawk@3.1.3: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as
this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated cryptiles@2.0.5: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated boom@2.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated sntp@1.0.9: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as
this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
npm WARN marvel@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code EINVAL
npm ERR! EINVAL: invalid argument, read

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-19T04_17_15_173Z-debug.log
```

Comment: try removing package ` package-lock.json` and then do npm install

Answer (score 0):

I never ran into this issue before but have you try deleting your `node_modules` directory and running `npm install` again or running `npm cache clean`?

Comment: I have tried both suggestions and nothing has worked. I am going to delete everything and start fresh. Hopefully that will do it?

Answer (score 0):

I updated both my npm and node. After that it allowed me to install request, thank you